# SQL: order by column alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

When I run this query:

```
SELECT 'A' as table_name, count() FROM A 
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' as table_name, count() FROM B
UNION ALL SELECT 'C' as table_name, count() FROM C ORDER BY table_name ASC;
```

The output is:

```
table_name  count
-----------------
B            0
C            0
A            0
```

It doesn't order by column table_name, how can I order it and get the output:

```
 table_name  count
 -----------------
  A            0
  B            0
  C            0
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7ebe921b04fa033db86ebe1d98055ad), and your current query should already be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
select * from
(
SELECT 'A' as table_name, count() FROM A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B' as table_name, count() FROM B
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C' as table_name, count() FROM C
)tbl ORDER BY table_name ASC
```

Comment: A subquery is _not_ required here.